# GCD Timer crashes with frequently

Tags: ios, objective-c, block, grand-central-dispatch

I have created a very simple timer with GCD dispatch_source and I receive this weird crash quite frequent. The code looks quite fine to me. If any one could explain the reason behind this, I would be very much glad.

```
@interface MyTimer ()

@property (nonatomic, strong, readonly) dispatch_queue_t queue;
@property (nonatomic, readonly) NSTimeInterval timeOutDuration;
@property (nonatomic, copy, readonly) dispatch_block_t callback;
@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_group_t group;

@property (nonatomic, strong) dispatch_source_t timer;

@end


@implementation MyTimer

- (instancetype)initWithQueue:(dispatch_queue_t)queue
                     callback:(dispatch_block_t)callback
              timeOutDuration:(NSTimeInterval)interval
{
    NSAssert(queue, @"queue must not be nil");
    NSAssert(callback, @"callback must not be nil");

    if (self = [super init]) {
        _queue = queue;
        _callback = [callback copy];
        _timeOutDuration = interval;
        _group = dispatch_group_create();
        [self setupTimer];
    }
    return self;
}

- (void)setupTimer
{
    self.timer = dispatch_source_create(DISPATCH_SOURCE_TYPE_TIMER, 0, 0, self.queue);
    dispatch_source_set_timer(self.timer, dispatch_time(DISPATCH_TIME_NOW, self.timeOutDuration * NSEC_PER_SEC), 0, 0);

    __weak typeof(self) weakSelf = self;
    dispatch_source_set_event_handler(self.timer, ^{
        __strong typeof(self) strongSelf = weakSelf;
        // crashes on the next line
        dispatch_group_async(strongSelf.group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), strongSelf.callback);
        dispatch_group_async(strongSelf.group, strongSelf.queue, ^{
            [strongSelf invalidate];
        });
    });
}

- (void)fire
{
    dispatch_resume(self.timer);
}

- (void)invalidate
{
    if (self.timer) {
        dispatch_source_cancel(self.timer);
        _timer = nil;
        _callback = nil;
    }
} 
@end
```

It usually crashes at this line,

```
  dispatch_group_async(strongSelf.group, dispatch_get_main_queue(), strongSelf.callback);
```

The crash does not happen always but is frequent. I could not understand the logic behind the crash.

Comment: Define "crash".  You mean the computer jumps off the table onto the floor?

Comment: What is the exception message for the "crash"?

Comment: A `dispatch_source_t` cannot be `strong` or `retain` in Xcode 7.1.1. Your code will not compile.

Comment: @Cœur - No, that's not true. If you're seeing that error, it's probably because you set compiler flag `-DOS_OBJECT_USE_OBJC=0`, which as described in `<os/object.h>`, turns off object behavior for GCD types. But I retested this in Xcode 7.1.1 (as well as Xcode 7.2 beta 3), and `strong` works fine.

Comment: You'll also get this error if you target OS X versions prior to 10.8 or iOS versions prior to 6, as that predates the object handling of GCD types, and thus requires manual `dispatch_retain` and `dispatch_release`.

Comment: You're right, I was targeting iOS5. Code is fine when targeting iOS6.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Suppose the timer queues the block for execution. While the block is pending, the `MyTimer` object's retain count goes to zero, and the `MyTimer` is deallocated. Then the weak reference `weakSelf` is set to nil.

Then the block executes. It creates `strongSelf` from `weakSelf`. Since `weakSelf` is nil by now, `strongSelf` is also nil. So `strongSelf.group` and `strongSelf.callback` both return nil, and you pass those nils to `dispatch_group_async`. Bad program! No biscuit!

To fix, check `strongSelf` immediately after creating it. If it's nil, just return.

I also note that you don't have a `dealloc` method in `MyTimer`. I suspect that a resumed GCD timer is retained, so it won't be invalidated/released when your `MyTimer` is deallocated.  You should probably add a `dealloc` that does `[self invalidate]`.